# How many data points to fit an ex-Gaussian distribution?

Tags: distributions, curve-fitting

I want to fit an ex-Gaussian distribution (which has three parameters: $\mu$, $\sigma$, and $\nu$) to reaction time data.

**How many data points are needed as a minimum to reasonably fit this distribution?**

I am aware that an answer to this question depends on many factors (e.g., how much data actually deviate from the theoretical distribution) and that "more is better" in general. Anyway, are there any rules-of-thumb, or publications which could point me to the needed minimum of data points?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I recall correctly, as sample size decreases, mu will manifest positive bias while tau will manifest negative bias. Sigma will manifest either positive or negative bias depending on true values of the other parameters. [This paper](https://doi.org/10.3758/BF03196299) compares two methods of fitting ex-Gaussians, and from the figures I'd probably avoid going below 40 observations.

Answer (score 0):

Since the parameters are estimated using maximum-likelihood method you have that

$$\sqrt{n}(\hat\theta -\theta)\to N(0,I_{\theta}^{-1}),$$

where $I_{\theta}$ is the [Fisher information matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher_information), and $\theta$ is the vector of parameters in question. Hence

$$Var(\hat\theta-\theta)\approx 1/nI_{\theta}^{-1}$$

If you have calculated $I_{\theta}^{-1}$ and you suspect the approximate values of true $\theta$, this will give you an idea of approximate variance. You can then work out what is the minimum number of points. This is not perfect solution, but as a rule of thumb it might work.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts on it; but I have to admit that your approach exceeds my mathematical abilities - I have no clue on how to approach this ;-)

Comment: No problem. I posted this answer to complement Mike's advice. I was just trying to quantify 30 points rule, i.e. if you have central limit theorem, then $n=30$ gives you 0.1 error. This is a very bad statement, since I do not speak about what is 0.1 error, but for thumb of rule it works. The main point is that the approximation error for assymptotic results where CLT is employed (which is the case for maximum likelihood) is always $c/\sqrt{n}$, where $c$ is the constant depending on the distribution.